# KCL Current Law calculations

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I hope you can help in relation to my KCL question which asks that I find the currents in i1, i2, i3 and is.

I'll also need to calculate the power dissipated by the resistors in the circuit and confirm that the power dissipated by the resistors is the same as the power supplied by the power source.

I have done some calculations below but I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

$$I1 = 20       I= V/R       = 0.25A       = 1.25W$$

$$I2 = 40       I= V/R       = 0.125A     = 0.625W$$

$$I3 = 80       I= V/R       = 0.0625A    = 0.3125W$$

$$Is = 10       I= V/R        = 0.5A        = 2.5W$$

Power dissipation = I(amps) x V

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The error you have made is forgetting about the 10\$\Omega\$ resistor - this reduces the voltage across the three parallel resistors and means that the power calculations you have made are about 50% too high. Also, your initial equations are wrong - you've said I1 = 20I and I2 = 40I and this is wrong because it implies I2 is twice as big as I1 and of course this can't be so - I1 is twice I2 which is twice I3.

Answer (score 1):

**Sanity check**

Current from 5V supply is \$\dfrac{5V}{10\Omega + parallel resistors}\$

Parallel resistors are \$\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{40}+\frac{1}{80}}\$ = 11.43 ohms

Therefore current is \$\dfrac{5V}{21.43\Omega}\$ = 233.33 mA and this means total power is 1.1667 W.

Voltage across the three parallel resistors = 5V - \$10\Omega\times 0.23333 = 2.6667V\$

From this you can calculate the currents in the individual resistors.

This is what you should be getting whatever method you use.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that there is 5V across each parallel connected resistor but there isn't since the voltage across the \$10 \Omega\$ series resistor *subtracts* from the source voltage.

Here's a hint to get you started correctly.  Find the equivalent resistance of the 3 parallel connected resistors, add that to the \$10 \Omega\$ series resistance and find the total current \$I_S\$.  When you have this, you can calculate:

(1) the total power delivered by the source

(2) the voltage across the series resistor and the associated power

(3) the current through each parallel resistor by current division